# Xamarin 'backgroundTint' в values.xml

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Я сделал даунгрейд Android SDK с **7.1** до **5.0**, после чего во время сборки стала выскакивать ошибка

> No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'backgroundTint'. MyMobApp.Android    Путь_до_проекта\MyMobApp.Android\Resources\ourcecache\AC4900C6613CEA240DFCE0AEBB0279EE\res\values\values.xml    111

Что самое удивительное - по данному пути нет ни файла **values.xml** ни даже папки **ourcecache**. Искал вручную и вставлял путь прямо в обозреватель.

**IDE:** MS VS 2017 Community

Откуда студия тянет этот файл и как это пофиксить?

Папки `bin`, `obj` удалял, удалял так же `.user` файл, перезапускал Windows / студию, делал clean как проекта отдельно, так и решения в целом, смотрел проектный файл - не нашёл.

Обнаружил, что файл `values.xml` есть в папке `проект\obj\Debug\resourcecache\AC4900C6613CEA240DFCE0AEBB0279EE\res\values`, пробовал полностью сносить папку Debug, но при сборке папка `resourcecache` появляется снова вместе со всем её содержимым. Откуда она генерируется?

**UPD:** Ничего не помогло кроме как создать новое решение и перетащить в него исходники из старого.

Comment: Пробовали сделать `Clean` - `Rebuild` в проекте?

Comment: @Nikita Да, и проекта, и решения целиком. Обнаружил, что файл 'values.xml' есть в папке 'проект\obj\Debug\resourcecache\AC4900C6613CEA240DFCE0AEBB0279EE\res\values', пробовал полностью сносить папку Debug, но папка resourcecache появляется снова вместе со всем её содержимым. Откуда она генерируется?